# Position buttons inline as a group?

Tags: html, css

I think I got stupid overnight.

Trying to figure out how to position those buttons as a group inline. Cant get the solution for 30 mins now.

Anyone know, or is it some major problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/uKyX7/1/

Here is the code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class="btn">a</div>
    <div class="btn">b</div>
    <div class="btn">c</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Set the `.btn` class to have `display:inline-block` http://jsfiddle.net/uKyX7/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you just try this?

```
.btn-group div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

That was all!

Here is the upated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/uKyX7/4/

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` to the class `.btn`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKyX7/3/)